# Extra feature on test set

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I convert categorical data into dummy variables with `get_dummies` and I get these columns in the training dataset:

| x_A | x_B | x_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

But in the test dataset I have the following columns:

| x_A | x_B | x_C | x_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Should I create a 'D' column in the training set with all the values set to zero to apply later the model on the test set?? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary features obtained from one-hot encoding a categorical feature must be obtained from the training set only. This implies that any new value in the test set cannot be used.

I recommend the following method: before encoding the variable in the training set, discard all the rare values (for examples the ones which have a frequency lower than 3) and replace them with a special value `unknown`. Training the model with this special value has two advantages:

- Rare values are very likely to cause overfitting.
- The `unknown` value lets the model decide what to do with these cases, so it can be used in the test set to replace any new rare value (if a value doesn't appear in the training set it must be rare).